Electron Update : Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
We are trying to update node from 12 to 20 and electron version from 11 to 31.
I have an Electron based application. we do webpack in the render process. It throws error when I run the app after update
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
Other relevant information:
here is the Error:

jsonp chunk loading:79 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
at jsonp chunk loading:79:1
at jsonp chunk loading:575:1
at startup:7:1

Note: Since it is an electron app:
config.target = "electron-renderer";
we have config-overrides file with below values:
/* eslint-disable */
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.target = 'electron-renderer';

  config.resolve = {
    ...config.resolve,
    alias: { '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') }
  };
 
  return config;
};

Before update versions

webpack version: ^4.46.2
Node.js version: 12.19.4
Electron version : 11.0.0

After Update versions

webpack version: ^4.46.2
Node.js version: 20.14.0
Electron version: 31.0.0

It is not working with Updated version. I have tried all possible solutions from this #10035.
None of the solutions worked for me.
